# How to treat parentheses around registers?

Tags: assembly

```
Given the following initial register values:
r2 = 6
r3 = 55
r4 = 0
r5 = 25

Given the following memory values:
Value 0x34 at address 55
Value 0x05 at address 65
Value 0x0D at address 80
Value 0x3C at address 81
Value 0x0A at address 82
Value 0xFF at address 83

Now execute the following Nios instructions    
line 1: add r4, r3, r5
line 2: ldb r4, 1(r4)
line 3: ldb r2, -5(r4)
```

What would the value of r4 be after executing line 2? And what would the value of r2 be after executing line 3?

I am new to assembly, but my best guess is:

I know line 1 results in the value of 80 in r4.

On line 2 it goes to the memory address 80 (stored in r4), but what does the "1" outside the parentheses do? Is that the offset of the memory address to begin reading the data? So would r4 be 0x0D?

The -5 throws me off for line 3...

Please help explain this problem.

Comment: Certainly the assembly syntax was explained before you were given this assignment.

Comment: Yes, it's an offset, so `1(r4)` will just use `1+r4` as address, i.e. `81`, so r4 will be `0x3c=60`. `-5(r4)` is then `-5+60=55`.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Lectures are sketchy at best and it doesn't help at all the the professor is nearly impossible to understand.

Comment: @Jester Thanks! Makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this manual: http://www-ug.eecg.toronto.edu/desl/manuals/n2cpu_nii51017.pdf

### ldb / ldbio       *— load byte from memory or I/O peripheral*

> Computes the effective byte address specified by the sum of rA and the
>   instruction's signed  16-bit immediate value. Loads register rB with
>   the desired memory byte, sign extending the  8-bit value to 32 bits.
>   In Nios II processor cores with a data cache, this instruction may
>   retrieve the desired data from the cache instead of from memory.

Based on this, I would interpret your code as:

```
add r4, r3, r5   # r4 = r3 + r5
ldb r4, 1(r4)    # r4 = *((signed char *)r4 + 1)
ldb r2, -5(r4)   # r2 = *((signed char *)r4 - 5)
```

According to you, r4 at line 1 will be 55 + 25 = 80. Then r4 at line 2 will be 0x3c (60). Then r2 will be *(60-5) = 0x34 (52).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.